# Can’t insert var into rowKey in Primeface’s datatable selectManyCheckbox

Tags: primefaces, datatable

**JAVA EE 7**
**Primefaces version:** 7
**JFS version:** 2.2

I need a datatable with the possibility to choose several rows.
I used  [Primefaces datatable - Selection](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml), but I encountered a problem that I’m finding hard to solve.
On setting the rowKey, the IDE does not resolve the `var` variable. It highlights it and only suggests to declare it as an external variable!

One workaround was to generate a rowKey in the bean:

```js
public String getKey() {
        // larger code for debugging purpose
        String number = ((int) (Math.random()*1000)) + "";
        this.key = number;
        return key;
}
```

With this change it draws the table, without any error. But When I try to get the event value with `onRowSelect()` it returns null, and I think it’s because of the rowKey.

So my questions are:
a) Why doesn’t the rowKey acknowledges the setted var, but accepts the bean, and a getter function?

b) What could possibly be the cause for the `SelectedEvent` returning null on `onRowSelect()`?

**View XTML**

```html
<p:dataTable id="checkboxDT" var="trainee" value="#{trainingPlanBean.trainees}" selection="#{trainingPlanBean.selectedTrainees}" rowKey="#{trainee.id}" style="margin-bottom:0">
  <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" update="" listener="#{trainingPlanBean.printPlan}" />
  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="" listener="#{trainingPlanBean.onRowSelect}" />
  <f:facet name="header">
    Checkbox
  </f:facet>
  <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center" />
  <p:column headerText="#{msg.IDNUMBER}">
    <h:outputText value="#{trainee.id}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="#{msg.NAME}">
    <h:outputText value="#{trainee.name}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="#{msg.EMAIL}">
    <h:outputText value="#{trainee.email}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="#{msg.INTERESTED}">
    <h:outputText value="#{trainee.interested}" />
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

**Bean** 
*Removed most of the methods for simplicity sake*

```js
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TrainingPlanBean implements Serializable {
  private String title;
  private String motive;
  private String interval;
  private String courseId;
  private int duration;
  private List < TrainingSessionDto > trainingSession;
  private List < UsersDto > trainees;
  private List < UsersDto > selectedTrainees;
  private String key;

  public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    UsersDto usersDto = ((UsersDto) event.getObject());
  }

  public void onRowUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {
    System.out.println(((UsersDto) event.getObject()).getId());
  }

  public String getKey() {
    String number = ((int)(Math.random() * 1000)) + "";
    this.key = number;
    return key;
  }

  public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
  }
}
```

**EDIT ADDED**
If I close the `p:datatable` tag it recognises `trainee` as a variable:

```
<p:dataTable id="checkboxDT" var="trainee"
                             value="#{trainingPlanBean.trainees}"
                             selection="#{trainingPlanBean.selectedTrainees}"
                             rowKey="#{trainee.id}"
                             />
```

Comment: Jsf 2.4? And can you make your code into a real [mcve]? See also https://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info remove composition, dialog, superfluous fields code etc

Comment: Jsf 2.2 sorry. Removed some code also…

Comment: Hi, copy paste the code you posted above in a new empty jsf project. Does it compile? Remove as much as you can until it compiles **and still results in the error**. And one question per question please